# confusion about mount options

Tags: linux, mount

I feel confused about mount options such as: `--bind`, `--make-unbindable` and `--make-shared` and could you please help me explain the below commands?

```
sudo "mount --bind #{vm_bind_mount} #{vm_bind_mount}"
sudo "mount --make-unbindable #{vm_bind_mount}"
sudo "mount --make-shared #{vm_bind_mount}"
```

EDIT:
In fact, I wonder why there are duplicate `#{vm_bind_mount}` in `mount --bind`?
In other words, does `mount --bind /tmp/foo /tmp/foo` make sense?

Answer (score 12):

`mount --bind` replicates a mount at another location. For example, after

```
mount --bind /foo /bar
```

then `/foo/something` and `/bar/something` are the same file (accessed through different paths). You can use `mount --bind` to replicate a subtree: `/foo` doesn't have to be a mount point.

An example where this is useful is to make parts of the directory tree available under a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). For example, if you run a web server chrooted in `/srv`, but you want to serve files under `/home/bob`, then you can replicate (part of) Bob's home directory under the server root:

```
mount --bind /home/bob/public_html /srv/home/bob
```

The options `--make-private`, `--make-shared`, `--make-slave` and `--make-unbindable` provide some control over bind mounts and over what happens if you mount another filesystem under `/foo` or `/bar` after doing `mount --bind /foo /bar`.

- By default, all mounts are private: if you mount a filesystem under `/foo` or `/bar`, this doesn't affect what is visible through the other path.
- If `/foo` has been declared shared before doing `mount --bind`, then if you later mount something either under `/foo` or `/bar`, it's visible through the other path as well.
- A slave mount is shared only in one direction: if `/foo` is shared and `/bar` is slave, then mounting something under `/bar` affects the view under `/foo` but the converse is not true.
- If `/foo` is declared unbindable, then `mount --bind /foo /bar` will fail.

Comment: Does mount --bind /tmp/foo /tmp/foo make sense?

Comment: @user2886717 Not really. It's an edge case. It can be observable (unless shared), but it would be confusing.

Comment: Could you please explain the commands chain of my question in your answer? In my question, the arguments of option --bind are the same.

Comment: @user2886717 Where did you see this? I don't think it's saying that the options are the same, but that they're both of type `vm_bind_mount`. However it's impossible to be sure without context.

Comment: `systemd`changed the default so that now "by default, all mounts are shared".

Comment: @user2886717, "Does mount --bind /tmp/foo /tmp/foo make sense?" does make sense indeed. It turns this dir into a mount-point. Sometimes it matters.

Answer (score 4):

From the `mount(8)` manpage:

> Since Linux 2.6.15  it  is  possible to mark a mount and its submounts
>   as shared, private,
>                 slave or unbindable. A shared mount provides ability to create mirrors of  that  mount  such
>                 that  mounts  and  umounts  within any of the mirrors propagate to the other mirror. A slave
>                 mount receives propagation from its master, but any not vice-versa.  A private mount carries
>                 no propagation abilities.  A unbindable mount is a private mount which cannot cloned through
>                 a bind operation. Detailed semantics is documented in  `Documentation/sharedsubtree.txt`  file
>                 in the kernel source tree.

The text file referred to is actually `Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt`; here's [a link to that file in the current stable kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.13.5).

Comment: thank you for your answer and I have looked up the documentation. However, I still feel confused about                           mount --bind /cdrom /cdrom
mount --make-shared /cdrom                                      What does duplicated /cdrom mean?